# Ruby on Rails app working locally but not on live server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything is working perfectly locally but when I tried to put the app live I've got this error:

```
Showing /home/rails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised: 

end of file reached
  (in /home/rails/app/assets/stylesheets/global.css.scss)
```

this is line 9

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

when I remove this line I get errors for javascript:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
```

What is the issue and how can it be fixed? 
Also not sure about the "end of file reached global.css.scss?"

below is this:

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__92412405316489023_40891780'

app/controllers/site_controller.rb:42:in `index'
```

On line 42 is the word "render"

```
  def index
    render
  end
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should have something to do with precompile. Try cleaning the asset precompile temp folder.

If that doesn't solve it, pl post the stack trace.

Comment: sorry do you mean the development folder in tmp/cache/assets?

Comment: Try running `rake assets:clobber ` if that doesn't work try `rake tmp:clear`